# django-ckeditor applying changes to content correctly but not applying change in admin

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-admin, wysiwyg

I have replaced default django admin with django-ckeditor

GoogleWebFonts installed, loading and applying font to content correctly.
Problem is changes not being applied in django admin.

Specifically,the source is correct (pressing the source button on ckeditor interface), showing the font applied correctly and therefore my content is changed to the font i want. But when i reload the page in admin it defaults back to a normal text, but still with the correct source code.

I have ran

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

and have my static url, static root, media url and media root assigned and working correctly.

I am using the editor by replacing my TextField

```
 models.py

 from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

 ...
 body = RichTextField()
 ...
```

And

```
 urls.py :

 url(r'^ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),


config.js:

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
// Define changes to default configuration here. For example:
// config.language = 'fr';
// config.uiColor = '#AADC6E';
config.extraPlugins = 'ckeditor-gwf-plugin';
config.font_names = 'GoogleWebFonts;' + config.font_names;

};
```

settings.py :

```
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': 'full',
    'height': 300,
    'width': 900,

},
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Just realised this adding plugins manually this program is actually garbage. Just tried installing codesnippets as well and not getting the correct color scheme. Absolute waste of time.